# Python: Get queue and emit messages via Flask-socketio, is this possible with a While True?

Tags: python, websocket, queue, flask-socketio

I have some working code, that gets data from a queue, processes it and then emits the data via Flask-socketio to the browser.

This works when there aren't many messages to emit, however when the workload increases it simply can't cope.

Additionally I have tried processing the queue without transmitting and this appears to work correctly.

So what I was hoping to do, is rather than emit every time the queue.get() fires, to simply emit whatever the current dataset is on every ping.

In theory this should mean that even if the queue.get() fires multiple times between ping and pong, the messages being sent should remain constant and won't overload the system.

It means of course, some data will not be sent, but the most up-to date data as of the last ping should be sent, which is sufficient for what I need.

Hopefully that makes sense, so on to the (sort of working) code...

This works when there are not a lot of messages to emit (the socketio sleep needs to be there, otherwise the processing doesn't occur before it tries to emit):

```
def handle_message(*_args, **_kwargs):

    try:
        order_books = order_queue.get(block=True, timeout=1)
    except Empty:
        order_books = None
        market_books = market_queue.get()

    uo = update_orders(order_books, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, eo, mb)
    update_market_book(market_books, mb, uo, market_catalogues, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading)
    socketio.sleep(0.2)
    emit('initial_market', {'message': 'initial_market', 'mb': json.dumps(mb), 'ob': json.dumps(eo)})
    socketio.sleep(0.2)
    emit('my_response2', {'message': 'pong'})

def main():
    socketio.run(app, debug=True, port=3000)
    market_stream.stop()
    order_stream.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works (but I'm not trying to emit any messages here, this is just the Python script getting from the queue and processing):

```
while True:
    try:
        order_books = order_queue.get(block=True, timeout=1)
    except Empty:
        order_books = None
        market_books = market_queue.get()

    uo = update_orders(order_books, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading, eo, mb)
    update_market_book(market_books, mb, uo, market_catalogues, mkt_runners, profitloss, trading)
    print(mb)
```

(The mb at the end is the current dataset, which is returned by the update_market_book function).

Now, I was hoping, by having the `While True` at the end, this could simply run and the function would return the latest dataset on every ping, however using the above, the `While True` only fires when the `main` function is taken out...which of course stops the socketio section from working.

So, is there a way I can combine both these, to achieve what I am trying to do and/or is there an alternative method I haven't considered that might work?

As always, I appreciate your advice and if the question is not clear, please let me know, so I can clarify any bits.

Many thanks!

Just adding a stack trace as requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\betfairlightweight\endpoints\login.py", line 38, in request
    response = session.post(self.url, data=self.data, headers=self.client.login_headers, cert=self.client.cert)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 332, in connect
    cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
  File "D:\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 279, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 507, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 507, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "D:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 507, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 489 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: You are sleeping for a total of 0.4 second each time you process a message. Are you sure that's correct? You will never be able to handle more than 2.5 orders per second. My recommendation, remove the first sleep, just keep the second one, but make it `socketio.sleep(0)`, which is the standard for sleep long enough to keep concurrency in the system.

Comment: If I don't have the first sleep then sometimes it (at least seems to) try to emit before processing, so I need the small pause.

That said, I set both to 0 and for now it functions, albeit I still have the same issue in that it receives the data via the queue at a much faster rate than it can send via websockets to the browser.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with threading, which I thought might help, but most solutions, involve setting up a queue again to share between threads, which I don't think would be of much use here as I'd just run into the same problem.

Somehow I need to process every message, but only emit every 1 in x...

Comment: How many items per second do you receive on your queue?

Comment: Well oddly running just now it only appears to be 1 per second, in some cases every 3 seconds, so the average time will be 1 message every 1.x seconds. However even then, whilst processing is fine on the server side, emitting via websockets simply doesn't work at that pace.

Comment: I honestly don't understand how you arrived at the conclusion that the emit is slow. Emits are asynchronous, all that happens when you call emit is that a packet is put in a queue for another background thread to pickup and deliver. There should be absolutely not trouble emitting at a rate of 1/sec. I assume you are using eventlet or gevent with this application? Have you done the monkey patching so that your queue becomes non-blocking?

Comment: Yep fair point, I did assume it was on the server side, but perhaps the issue is on the client side, not being able to process the received messages quickly enough.

With regards to monkey patching, I can't use eventlet without errors for some reason, but I have been using gevent, with the following right at the top of my code:

`from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()`

Comment: Eventlet and gevent are fairly similar, can't think of any reason why eventlet would give you errors and gevent would work.

Comment: I haven't been able to work it out either, but with eventlet I always get a: `Exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error, whereas with gevent I don't for some reason!

Comment: Stack trace of the error?

Comment: no problem, just added in the main body.

Comment: Eventlet and gevent both have had occasional problems with openssl. In many cases the problem is caused by monkey-patching that happens too late (i.e. after the ssl support is imported). Try running your server w/o TLS. My recommendation is that you move TLS to a reverse proxy server such as nginx.

Comment: Ok cool tks, will give that a go!